# How exactly does this code work?

Tags: c, list, struct, typedef

I have this code:

```
struct list_element {
    int value;
    struct list_element *next;
};

typedef struct list_element listelement;
```

The above is not the problem. I get that. But what does the following do?

```
typedef listelement * list;
```

I want to create a struct list, that is similar to the empty list in python. I was told that the above does that, but I don't get how this works.

Comment: Linked lists: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html

Comment: Please google "typedef", there are lots of answers...

Comment: Note: **Never ever** `typedef` a pointer to a datatype!

Comment: Too short for an answer; but consider how you can actually create an empty list: `listelement *list1 = NULL`. The last line of code, with the `typedef`, makes it possible to shorten this to `list list1 = NULL`.

Comment: @Olaf `PVOID`, `PWCSTR`?

Comment: @arminb: Are they standard C names? What do you want to say?

Comment: @Olaf No, but a popular OS defined them (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @arminb: And that means … what? The more than 30 year old WinAPI is an example for bad coding style? That's the opposite of news (and wide-spread is not the same as "popular"). How does that be a counter-argument for what I wrote? Heck, when those were defined, there was not even the `const` wualifer in C. Try writing qualtifier-correct code with such `typedef`s! You ned at least two names. All this just to save typing a `*`? Do you have **any** reasonable argument for such a `typedef` (I mean something other than "I don't like stars"?

Comment: @arminb: Btw: Most devices do **not** use Windows. The systems without this outnumber the systems with by multiple decades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically a `typedef`  creates a type alias.

So the first one creates the alias `listelement` for `struct list_element`.

The second builds upon that, and creates the alias `list` for `listelement *` (which of course is just a `struct list_element *`).

In general, using `typedef` to "hide" pointers can be clumsy and annoying, since in C you really need to care quite often whether something is a pointer or not.

Comment: A data-type pointer should **never** be `typedef`ed. Readability is just one aspect, but there is a simple functional aspect much more important: If you want qualifier-correct code, you need much more `typedef`s. Otherwise you cannot write e.g. const-correct code. And that makes the file-namespace explode.

Comment: @Olaf Agreed, but it's not the really an issue with the answer if the question is the source of this `typedef`? =)